# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

Tags: php

Following is my php code:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
    include 'dbconnection.php';
    try{
        if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $return_arr = array();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT JOBNO FROM PRTJOBHD WHERE JOBNO LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['JOBNO'];
        }

        } 
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

I'm getting a error that "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.0.102/ipack/search.php?term=a. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)." while running on browser.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Are you using apache or iis, it seems like the headers not working from your php file and you may need to configure CORS in your virtual host configuration. I'd recommend adding CORS as a tag to your question as well. Here is how to configure it for apache http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: I agree with Engin, if you're running apache2 you should try enabling CORS

Comment: @Robotia, How to enable CORS?

Comment: @VipinKA sudo a2enmod headers then put " <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>" in your apache2.conf